# позиция контекстного меню при выделении текста Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, position

[[image: Как изменить расположение контестного меню при выделении текста в EditText. Необходимо чтобы контекстное меню располагалось ниже текста]][[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r08LD.jpg)

Как изменить расположение контекстного меню при выделении текста в EditText. Необходимо чтобы контекстное меню располагалось ниже текста][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r08LD.jpg)][![введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего так разместить его снизу не получится, т.к. это контекстное меню ОС